# LinearLayout: 3 Elements, Top, Center, Bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I've the following xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_00" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a Test"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- The first FrameLayout contains a fragment, which contains some buttons.
- The RelativeLayout contains for example an image (changig size) and a text.
- The last FrameLayout contains also a fragment, which contains either some buttons or some text or an image.

**My aim is, that:**
- the first FrameLayout is on top (that works)
- the elements in the RelativeLayout are centered in the middle of the screen (doesn't work)
- the last FrameLayout is on the bottom (doesn't work)

It should look like this:

[image]

My previous attempts with `android:gravity="center"` in the `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"` for the second `FrameLayout` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `LineareLayout` to `Relative` and use [layout_centerInParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerInParent) for the middle layout and [`alignParentBottom`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentBottom) for the last one.

The top `View` will be anchored to the top by default

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> //removed orientation as it won't be needed anymore

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" // change here
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centernInParent="true">  // here

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_00" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a Test"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" /> //here

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. The FrameLayout fragment is now at the bottom. But the image and text are not centered horizontally  (only vertically)

Comment: @Struct I have updated. You need to change the width of that inner RL.

Comment: Change the inner `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` for better performance

Comment: @Lamorak yes a `LinearLayout` would make sense here and can have better performance but in a simple layout the difference won't be noticed. However, with a more complex layout, it could be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative layout and use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` instead of gravity.

**EDIT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/topFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_00"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a Test"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you too. Here is the same problem as in the other answer. The FrameLayout fragment is now at the bottom. But the image and text are not centered horizontally (only vertically)

Comment: Added center horizontal to other elements and things should be fine.